# Trouble writing data to variable in google sheets apt script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to create a google sheet where I can take some data that has an area on it and create brand new sheets based off a region. The idea being that these can then be sent out individually to the region. I am trying to put the region into a variable (regionname) to then be able to do the iteration however it keeps referencing back to data on a different sheet

```
function SplitMacro() {

  /**Clear the old data from Working_sheet**/
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D7').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Working_Sheet'));
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

  /**Get a list of all the regions, this will be branches later, and put into the working sheet**/
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('All_Data'));
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:A').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Working_Sheet'));

  /**De dup the regions so have a unique list**/
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('All_Data!A:A').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:A').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().removeDuplicates().activate(); 

  /**Get the number of regions that need to split out on**/
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('UserInputs'));
  var noregion = activeSheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  var filename = activeSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  Logger.log(noregion); //comments out the line
  Logger.log(filename);
  //spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Working_Sheet'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Working_Sheet'));
  for(var i=1; i<=2; i++) {
    Logger.log("Hello");    
    /**Get the region data to then filter on and for the naming convention on the new sheet**/
    var regionname = activeSheet.getRange(i+1,1).getValue();
    Logger.log(regionname);
  }
}
```

Comment: To clear the sheet before you start you can call `activeSheet.clear()` it will empty the entire sheet, ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clear)). Also, is there a reason  you keep calling `activate()`? You don't need it to work with the ranges, what it does is basically select the range in the sheet ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate)). Lastly, you're setting `activeSheet` to be "Working_Sheet" is that not the intention?